# I can't delete a row from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

Here is the code

```
<?
$x=$_SESSION["name"];
mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE from Uzivatel WHERE username='$x'");
mysqli_close($mysqli);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

I saved username into `$_SESSION["name"]` at the previous page. Here I just load it into `$x` and I want to delete row from database where `username = $x` but I can't and I don't know why.

If I change `$x` in the SQL command into normal string name like Hed (for example) it will delete him. But if I want to delete it through variable, nothing happens.

And yes I checked if the username is in the `$_SESSION["name"]` through echo, and yes it's there.

Comment: What's the value of `$mysqli` right before the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start the session before you can use a SESSION variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
$x=$_SESSION["name"];
mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE from Uzivatel WHERE username='$x'");
mysqli_close($mysqli);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```